# How can i convert an image to input vector for perceptron algorithm?

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, classification, perceptron

I need to implement a simple perceptron algorithm. There are 2 classes "cat and dogs". Each training sample is a pair of the form `(x,t)` where `x` is the vector of input values, and `t` is target output value. But i don't know how can i convert an image to a vector form in python for perceptron?
What is meant by vector form?

Images have a size 32*32.

Comment: Images are 32x32 thus you have 1024 values: this is your vector! Just concat all the columns for example...

Answer (score 1):

Perceptron only deal with vector not matrix. So you should flatten your image to be a vector. So if you have a batch of images of shape like (1000,32,32) you can do this:

```
x = x.reshape((len(x), x.shape[1]*x.shape[2]))
```

In the future, if you still want to deal with images, have a look at Convolutional Neural Network (CNN).

Comment: you mean `x = x.reshape(1, x.shape[1]*x.shape[0])` if `x` is `32x32` ?

Comment: Yes, I considered that you are dealing with a batch of images so something like (100,32,32)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an image `a` of size `32x32`:

```
>>> a=np.random.random((32,32))
>>> a.shape
(32, 32)
```

Then you can transform it to a vector to feed the perceptron by:

```
>>> b=a.reshape(1,1024)
>>> b.shape
(1, 1024)
```